# How do i filter duplicates in a Access Subreport displaying images (stored in a attacment field) by using a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to filter this query i a way that there are no duplicates of the product name/id so that the attachment field is only displayed once. I am using this query for a access (sub)report. With this result it is displaying the attachment twice or more (depending how Manny times the same products is selected  in the order form).

```
SELECT OrderDetailsTbl.OrderDetailsID, ProductTbl.ProductID,
       ProductTbl.ServiceNaam, ProductTbl.omschrijving
FROM ProductTbl
  INNER JOIN OrderDetailsTbl ON ProductTbl.ProductID = OrderDetailsTbl.ProductID;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with : HAVING (((OrderDetailsTbl.OrderID)=[Formulieren]![OrderFrm]![OrderID])); !!